# Downloading scipy 1.4.1 using pip 20

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, scipy, pip

I like to use pip to download the source of Python packages, without installing them. To download e.g. SciPy 1.4.1 I would use

```sh
python3 -m pip download --no-binary=:all: scipy==1.4.1
```

This generally works, but for at least SciPy 1.4.1 and pip 20.0, 20.0.1 and 20.0.2 it does not.

The SciPy source is in fact downloaded, but due to an error in the "Installing build dependencies" step, the SciPy source is being cleaned up. (I don't really want this build step, but even supplying `--no-deps` doesn't get rid of it. It doesn't actually install anything though.)

What's changed with pip, and (more importantly) how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if I add the [`--no-use-pep517`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/#cmdoption-use-pep517) option:

```sh
python3 -m pip download --no-binary=:all: --no-use-pep517 scipy==1.4.1
```

Comment: Is this behaviour a pip regression then? There's no reason for it to unpack the source either way, right?

Answer (score 1):

This also could be fixed with

```
pip install -U virtualenv pip
virtualenv .venv --seeder pip
source .venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip download --no-binary=:all: scipy==1.4.1
```

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the behaviour?